# The Javascript Datastore Problem

Tags: javascript, database, security, html

This might sound super crazy but I really want to know if this can be done.

Assume a multi-user site that gives users some tools to build web apps from the site itself (using only HTML/CSS/JS) and *share* them. Now, if each of the apps were to be assigned a *datastore*, say just a table for convenience, is it possible to make secure query/insert requests from the app to the backend to write to the assigned table.

Take an example - the app is a small game. The developer wants to record the scores of the users who play the game and wants to use his assigned datastore (see above) for it. Is it possible for the site to ensure that no other app/user can access this datastore? If so, how can it be done?

**Edit**: Please do note that there are three parties involved - the *developer* of the app who is a registered user, the *app* itself which has been granted the datastore and an *app user* (registered/unregistered) who is viewing the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the same as using any type of backend datastore for any web app. You could assign the user a unique ID (which they have to validate by logging in) and then manage access to the datastore through AJAX post backs.

Comment: There is a small difference, right? The app itself is public. So, the DB write request will be made from the app when it is run (from Javascript).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by public?

Comment: By public, I mean that it can be viewed by anyone. Have edited the question. Hope it makes it slightly clearer.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's a bit more clear. One way I can think of is using subdomains for each app (perhaps using mod_rewrite in apache or an ISAPI filter in IIS). The subdomains will prevent cross-site scripting even across subdomains and you can use the subdomain in your postback pages to determine which data store should be accessed.